# Which one is better: Java ScheduledExecutorService or Spring framework @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am adding code to existing project written based on Spring framework. So wondering which one I should choose: Java `ScheduledExecutorService` or Spring framework `@Scheduled` ?

I see another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457452/spring-task-scheduler-vs-javas-scheduledexecutorservice), which claims using spring framework version, but I don't quite understand the reason. What I think is if use `ScheduledExecutorService` , it looks like more under my control than the Spring framework `@Scheduled`.

Comment: Neither. Use whichever one suits you best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already using Spring framework in your project, then you might as well schedule your task using @Scheduled annotation because it is easy to set it up compared to Java's ScheduledExecutorService.

But if your project doesn't use Spring framework, I'd just stick to Java's version of Scheduler.